# Laptop keyboard stops working after x2x install and use

Tags: gnome, keyboard, ssh

I'm new to linux/ubuntu and I have encountered a little problem: After installing x2x (following [ubuntu community documentation about x2x](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X2xHowto)) my laptop keyboard no longer works. The x2x system worked great - I was able to control my laptop from the desktop which was ssh'd into it... but the keyboard on the laptop no longer works. I have a dual-boot, and when I boot into lion (it's an early 2008 macbook) the keyboard works fine. Also, if I use a wireless usb mouse/keyboard when in ubuntu they work... just the actual computer hardware doesn't. Help?

Summary:

- **Installed x2x, worked great**
- **Now the keyboard on my laptop dosen't work when logged into Ubuntu, but works in native OS (mac, lion)**

**Edit:**

Additionally, if I log into a guest account in Ubuntu they keyboard works fine... So I'm assuming there's something wrong just in my main account.

Comment: Also, here are the instructions I followed for x2x: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X2xHowto

Comment: You can always edit your question to give additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone runs into this problem it turns out I accidentally hit NumLock on the keyboard that was ssh'd into my mac. Hitting numlock again fixed the issue. I'm not a smart man...